# Set active cell with value from another workbook

Tags: vba

I need to put a value in the first empty cell in column B of the current sheet.
The value has to be read from another workbook identified with absolute path.

That's my not working attempt:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("B1").Select
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Value = "=[C:\Users\Manu...\Source.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"
End Sub
```

I get error 1004 on the last line.
How can I correct?
If possible, I would prefer not to open the source workbook.

Comment: what is not working? what kind of error you have?

Comment: Last line, error 1004 (no further information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is correct attempt to write formula (which you try to write into first empty cell):

```
ActiveCell.Value = "='C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1"
```

Look at the positions of `single quotation marks` and `square brackets`.